# FullClendar :: Calendar issue in angular5 application

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Hi all i'm using following
calendar in my angular5 application

[ng-fullcalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-fullcalendar)

I have implemented as below

HTML Code

```
<div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
    <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar 
    [options]="calendarOptions" 
    (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)"
    [(eventsModel)]="events"></ng-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

My component.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarComponent } from 'ng-fullcalendar';
import { Options } from 'fullcalendar';
import { EventSesrvice } from './event.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-calendar',
    templateUrl: './calendar.component.html'
})
export class AppCalendarComponent implements OnInit {

    calendarOptions:Options;
    data: any[];

    @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) ucCalendar: CalendarComponent;
    constructor(private eventService: EventSesrvice) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.eventService.getEvents().
        subscribe(suc => {this.data = suc, console.log(this.data)});
        if (this.data.length != 0) {
            this.calendarOptions = {
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: false,
                header: {
                  left: 'prev,next today',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: this.data
              };
        }

    }

    eventClick(item) {
        console.log(item);
    }

    clickButton(item) {
        console.log(item);
    }

}
```

My Service.ts code

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
@Injectable()
export class EventSesrvice {
    public getEvents(): Observable<any> {
        const dateObj = new Date();
        const yearMonth = dateObj.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1);
        let data: any = [{
            DoctorsCount: 5,
            TotalAppointments: 20,
            Booked: 10,
            Cancelled: 2
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event111',
            start: yearMonth + '-07',
            end: yearMonth + '-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: yearMonth + '-09'
        }];
        return Observable.of(data);
    }
};
```

I am able to display last two objects in the calendar but i am unable to display below object which is first object in service.ts

```
            {
                DoctorsCount: 5,
                TotalAppointments: 20,
                Booked: 10,
                Cancelled: 2
            }
```

how to show all data in side the calendar (i mean above object)

You can find demo in below link

<kbd>[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)</kbd>

I have tried like below in service.ts code

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
@Injectable()
export class EventSesrvice {
      obj = {DoctorsCount: 5,
        TotalAppointments: 20,
        Booked: 10,
        Cancelled: 2};
    public getEvents(): Observable<any> {
        const dateObj = new Date();
        const yearMonth = dateObj.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1);
        let data: any = [{
            DoctorsCount: 5,
            TotalAppointments: 20,
            Booked: 10,
            Cancelled: 2
        },
        {
            title : JSON.stringify(this.obj),
            start: yearMonth + '-08',
            end: yearMonth + '-9'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event111',
            start: yearMonth + '-07',
            end: yearMonth + '-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: yearMonth + '-09'
        }];
        return Observable.of(data);
    }
};
```

it is displaying as below[image]

is it correct???

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried as below     obj = {DoctorsCount: 5,
        TotalAppointments: 20,
        Booked: 10,
        Cancelled: 2};

Comment: @Stackfan please see the question once which i have tried as per your previous answer

Comment: i have mentioned start date  as below  {
            title : JSON.stringify(this.obj),
            start: yearMonth + '-08',
            end: yearMonth + '-9'
        },

Comment: please see below lines in the edited question you can find it

Comment: i have mentioned in the below lines of the service.ts code at let data: any[..... section

Comment: no, data is not showing  as per your last comment. only 4p is showing,   plesae see the question once i have added new screenshot which i have implemented as per you last comment

Comment: yes it is working for me also, you can find  it from the first picture in the question,  but it is not suitable to our requirement

Comment: please see the  3rd picture (i have collected from pdf from my UI Designer). i have to show in that format only

Comment: Thank you very much please let me know if you get any update, which is suitable to our requirement

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I second what @Sajeetharan said: the question is not clear. The calendar is actually showing what is being passed with the data array. And, what is the last picture showing?

Answer (score 5):

For my understanding, do you want to add custom data in an event?
If your object is:

```
{
    DoctorsCount: 4,
    TotalAppointments: 19,
    Booked: 9,
    Cancelled: 1
}
```

just add the event key: (`start`,`end`) with it and you will be able to render in the calendar, for example:

```
{
    DoctorsCount: 4,
    TotalAppointments: 19,
    Booked: 9,
    Cancelled: 1,
    start: yearMonth + '-01',
}
```

then in the calendar's event click which is, you can get these object by $event.detail.event

in your code you use: `(eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)"`

and

```
eventClick(model: any) {
    // you can get current DoctorsCount by 
    model.event.DoctorsCount
      model = {
          event: {
            id: model.event.id,
            start: model.event.start,
            end: model.event.end,
            title: model.event.title,
            allDay: model.event.allDay,
            // other params
            DoctorsCount: model.event.DoctorsCount,
            TotalAppointments: model.event.TotalAppointments,
            Booked: model.event.Booked,
            Canceled: model.event.Canceled
          },
          duration: {}
    }
    this.displayEvent = model; 
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your question is not clear, I see in your comments that you want to have to display like the 3rd pics, so your solution is by customising the rendering with `eventRender`

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
    <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar 
    [options]="calendarOptions" 
    (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)"
    [(eventsModel)]="events"
    (eventRender)="eventRender($event.detail)"></ng-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

and in your component.ts

```
eventRender(e) {
    const html = `<ul>
      <li>DoctorsCount: ${e.event.DoctorsCount}</li>
      <li>TotalAppointments: ${e.event.TotalAppointments}</li>
      <li>Booked: ${e.event.Booked}</li>
       <li>Cancelled: ${e.event.Cancelled}</li>
    </ul>`;
    e.element.html(html)
}
```

and your service:

```
let data: any = [{
        start: yearMonth + '-01',
        DoctorsCount: 5,
        TotalAppointments: 20,
        Booked: 10,
        Cancelled: 2
    },
    {
        start: yearMonth + '-02',
        DoctorsCount: 8,
        TotalAppointments: 20,
        Booked: 10,
        Cancelled: 2
    },
    ...
```

This is the updated demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo-ujqghm

Comment: Thanks @Fetrarij, I have displayed custom data, my new issue is , I would like to know event name that is fired when I click on day wise, week wise

Comment: You can set and get an event id or name like this method.

Comment: @Santhosh  I have updated the answer and the demo to have it looks like the 3rd pics

Comment: you can't just ask another question @Santhosh. One question per question.